# Finding all possible combinations of positive and negative numbers that equal a given sum

Tags: c#, algorithm

How would you go if you want to see in how many ways you can combine the numbers from 1 to N in such a way that by using addition or subtraction you will end up with combinations that equal a given target number.

In regards to this topic [Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum), I was unable to modify it in a way that I could achieve my result, so I decided to ask instead.

Example: (Lets say that N = 8. How would I approach to solve this if I create the following array from 1 to N. Don't use each number more than once.)

- arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
- sum = 0;

Result:

- +1 +2 +3 +4 -5 -6 -7 +8
- +1 +2 +3 -4 +5 -6 +7 -8
- +1 +2 -3 +4 +5 +6 -7 -8
- +1 +2 -3 -4 -5 -6 +7 +8
- +1 -2 +3 -4 -5 +6 -7 +8
- +1 -2 -3 +4 +5 -6 -7 +8
- +1 -2 -3 +4 -5 +6 +7 -8
- -1 +2 +3 -4 +5 -6 -7 +8
- -1 +2 +3 -4 -5 +6 +7 -8
- -1 +2 -3 +4 +5 -6 +7 -8
- -1 -2 +3 +4 +5 +6 -7 -8
- -1 -2 +3 -4 -5 -6 +7 +8
- -1 -2 -3 +4 -5 +6 -7 +8
- -1 -2 -3 -4 +5 +6 +7 -8
- Total Solutions: 14

Comment: It seems unclear to me. What is this sum that you are looking for? How do you calculate it? How do you use the array showed to get the 'sum'?

Comment: Can you clarify what is 'not correct' about the c# answer given on the link to the [other SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum) article you gave?

Comment: edited, the target in the example is 0. @Luuk not that something is incorrect, but i'm unable to modify it in a way for it to work with positive and negative numbers.

Comment: It is also unclear why `+1 -1 +2 -2 +3 -3 +4 -4` can be a solution and `+5 -5 +6 -6 +7 -7 +8 -8` is missing from your list of possible solutions

Comment: you need to write down all rules to the problem. As per your rules I can do anything i want with any number i want, giving an infinite number or combinations possible

Comment: @CarlosGarcia I understand, sorry. I have worded the question differently now and I hope it makes more sense.

Comment: `+1 -1 +2 -2 +3 -3 +4 -4` so you can use each number more than once, and you don't need to use all numbers? Again... infinite solution. You need to provide a rule to stop the iterations (get the first 20 or don't use each number more than once, etc)

Comment: @CarlosGarcia omg thanks for pointing that out. I't seems i have put "+1 -1 +2 -2 +3 -3 +4 -4" this incorrectly, since I was testing something out. The rule is that i don't want to use each number more than once. Edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a recursive function that will print all the combinations that worked, and the ones that did not work.

### The code (test it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LwzvHK), or a simpler version [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BnBIo6)):

```
// This code can be improved a lot, but i wrote it in the way that i believe it is easier to read and understand what it does.

using System;

namespace algorithm_simple_csharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Working on it!");

            int[] allNumbers = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
            int desiredSum = 0;

            // We will create two trees, one with a positive first number, and the other one with a negative one

            // Positive tree
            int initIndex = 0;
            OperationTreeNode firstPositiveNode = new OperationTreeNode
            {
                parentNode = null,
                currentNumber = allNumbers[initIndex],
                accumulativeSum = allNumbers[initIndex],
                operation = "+"
            };

            int totalSolutionsPositiveFirst = ApplyNumber(firstPositiveNode, allNumbers, initIndex + 1, desiredSum);

            // Negative tree
            OperationTreeNode firstNegativeNode = new OperationTreeNode
            {
                parentNode = null,
                currentNumber = -allNumbers[initIndex],
                accumulativeSum = -allNumbers[initIndex],
                operation = "-"
            };

            int totalSolutionsNegativeFirst = ApplyNumber(firstNegativeNode, allNumbers, initIndex + 1, desiredSum);

            // Print all solutions found with both trees
            Console.WriteLine("Total soltions: " + (totalSolutionsPositiveFirst + totalSolutionsNegativeFirst));
        }


        // This function will take care of the next number we should apply: allNumbers[index]
        // If there are still numbers to apply, It will create two nodes, one for + allNumbers[index] and one for - allNumbers[index]
        static int ApplyNumber(OperationTreeNode currentNode, int[] allNumbers, int index, int desiredSum)
        {

            // The base case, There are no more numbers to cover.
            // In that case we evaluate if the last node is equal to desiredSum or not
            if(index > allNumbers.GetUpperBound(0))
            {
                if(currentNode.accumulativeSum == desiredSum)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(currentNode.BranchToString() + " = " + currentNode.accumulativeSum + "  <---   THIS ONE");
                    return 1;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(currentNode.BranchToString() + " = " + currentNode.accumulativeSum);
                return 0;
            }

            // If it is not the last node, then we create two child nodes of the current node.
            // First we evaluate what happens if we apply a + to the next number...
            OperationTreeNode plusNode = new OperationTreeNode
            {
                parentNode = currentNode,
                currentNumber = allNumbers[index],
                accumulativeSum = currentNode.accumulativeSum + allNumbers[index],
                operation = "+"
            };
            int totalSolutionsWithPlus = ApplyNumber(plusNode, allNumbers, index +1, desiredSum);

            // Now we evaluate what happens if we apply a - to the next number...
            OperationTreeNode minusNode = new OperationTreeNode
            {
                parentNode = currentNode,
                currentNumber = allNumbers[index],
                accumulativeSum = currentNode.accumulativeSum - allNumbers[index],
                operation = "-"
            };
            int totalSolutionsWithMinus = ApplyNumber(minusNode, allNumbers, index +1, desiredSum);

            // The total number of solutions we found is the sum of the solutions of both sub-trees
            return totalSolutionsWithPlus + totalSolutionsWithMinus;
        }

    }


    public class OperationTreeNode
    {
        public int accumulativeSum = 0;
        public OperationTreeNode parentNode = null;
        public int currentNumber = 0;
        public string operation;

        public string BranchToString()
        {
            if(parentNode == null)
            {
                return $"{this.currentNumber} ";
            }

            return $"{parentNode.BranchToString()} {this.operation} {this.currentNumber} ";
        }
    }
}
```

### The output in the console

```
Working on it!
1  + 2  + 3  + 4  = 10
1  + 2  + 3  - 4  = 2
1  + 2  - 3  + 4  = 4
1  + 2  - 3  - 4  = -4
1  - 2  + 3  + 4  = 6
1  - 2  + 3  - 4  = -2
1  - 2  - 3  + 4  = 0  <---   THIS ONE
1  - 2  - 3  - 4  = -8
-1  + 2  + 3  + 4  = 8
-1  + 2  + 3  - 4  = 0  <---   THIS ONE
-1  + 2  - 3  + 4  = 2
-1  + 2  - 3  - 4  = -6
-1  - 2  + 3  + 4  = 4
-1  - 2  + 3  - 4  = -4
-1  - 2  - 3  + 4  = -2
-1  - 2  - 3  - 4  = -10
Total soltions: 2
```

### How it works?

It creates a tree. Each node of the tree is an object of type `OperationTreeNode` that represents a number and its operation. for example: +1 and -1 are two `OperationTreeNode`

when you reached the last number, `ApplyNumber` will evaluate if the node is equal to `desiredSum`.

`ApplyNumber` returns how many solutions that subtree found

Comment: thanks for the answer, however it seems that i'm probably mistaken and I'm not able to understand my problem well, because your solution is definitely correct, but it does not solve my problem according to the example. If i run your code for the example I gave, e.g arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], targetSum = 0; I will get 7 total solutions instead of 14. Is your code checking if we have +1 or a -1 at the first index of the array? (thanks beforehand)

Comment: @Knightwalker no it does not :) here it is executing two trees, one with the positive first index, one with the negative one: dotnetfiddle.net/O4IeRd. You can also make a nicer code. For example, this is already shorter and it prints only the succeeded cases: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MP4U0f

Comment: man I really appreciate the help and the explanations! You are correct. I hope that I will reach your level someday. This might seem like basic recursive function to you, but for a beginner like me its hell, lol.

Comment: @Knightwalker You will get very good! :)   If my code was hard to understand, this is the same algorithm but much simpler (without using objects): https://dotnetfiddle.net/BnBIo6

Comment: The output in the console: -1  + 2  + 3  + 4  = 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know,  and if i've understood the question, you need a `for` loop since if you have a number `n`, there are infinite combinations of numbers that added or subtracted equals `n`, so you need a number that, if reached will stop the process.
If you need multiple number (e.g. 3+10+1=14) you need more loops.
This would be my way to go:

```
int l = 50;//my limit
int n = 14;//my number
for(int i = 0; i < l; i++) 
        {
           for(int j = 0; j < l; j++) 
           {
                if ( i + j == n ) 
                {
                //Do whatever you want
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1} + {2}", n, i, j);
                }
                if ( i - j == n ) 
                {
                //Do whatever you want
                       Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1} - {2}", n, i, j);
                }
         }
      }//Repeat for negative numbers
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Iterative, how many ways to reach a target.

```
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(C(0));
        int[] a = { 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144 };
        Console.Write(C(0, a)); Console.Read();
    }

    static int C(int t)  // ±1 ± 2 ± 3 ± 4 == 0
    {
        int c = 0, s = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < 16; n++)
        {
            if ((n & 1) == 0) s -= 1; else s += 1;
            if ((n & 2) == 0) s -= 2; else s += 2;
            if ((n & 4) == 0) s -= 3; else s += 3;
            if ((n & 8) == 0) s -= 4; else s += 4;
            if (s == t) c++; s = 0;
        } return c;
    }

    static int C(int t, int[] a)
    {
        int c = 0, s = 0, i, j = a.Length, n, m = 1 << j;
        for (n = 0; n < m; n++)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
                if ((n & 1 << i) == 0) s -= a[i]; else s += a[i];
            if (s == t) c++; s = 0;
        } return c;
    }
}
```